# Is there a way to include a spring component in a WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-web, spring-test-mvc, spring-mvc-test

Given production code classes:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private final MyValidator validator;

    // annotations relating to request mapping excluded for brevity 
    public void test(@Valid @RequestBody final MyParams params) {
        // do stuff
    }

    @InitBinder
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    ...

    @Override
    public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors) {
        // custom validation
    }
}
```

and finally test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    // tests
}
```

I encounter the error:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'MyValidator' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I think the error is fair enough. I've annotated the test as a WebMvcTest, which I believe has excluded `@Component` beans. This is intentional and desired (from the perspective that I am only wanting to test the "web layer", not the whole context - it just so happens I need a component which is related/used only in the controllers)

My question, therefore, is: how can one explicitly include a component like a validator in the test context for a web test?

My environment is java `version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17`, spring boot `1.5.16.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to test the web layer

first.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyController myController;
}
```

> The @SpringBootTest annotation tells Spring Boot to go and look for a
>   main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication for
>   instance), and use that to start a Spring application context.
>
> A nice feature of the **Spring Test** support is that the application
>   context is cached in between tests, so if you have multiple methods in
>   a test case, or multiple test cases with the same configuration, they
>   only incur the cost of starting the application once. You can control
>   the cache using the @DirtiesContext annotation.

Secondly, if you want to use the @WebMvcTest(MyController.class)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private MyValidator validator;

}
```

But this validator is a fake, so you have to customize it for testing.

See this link for more details https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: Is it true to say that the first approach detailed above would likely (perhaps depending on other configuration found on the `SpringBootApplication` class) be starting the entire spring context (all services, repositories, components, etc...). The second approach is what I'm already doing - I could use a fake validator and write separate unit tests for the validator logic to cover the implementation. I'll also experiment with having a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` define the beans - as i think these beans would then apply in the context.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot recommend it as a standard practice but if you do need an instance of a dependency in your Web MVC tests (for example in legacy code) you can add them into the spring context using [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) annotation.

Real methods of that class will be called during the test and you can verify them if needed similarly to the beans annotated with `@MockBean`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @SpyBean
    private MyValidator validator
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this.

1. Using @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureMvc instead of @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @WebMvcTest.

   ```
   @SpringBootTest
   @AutoConfigureMvc
   public class MyControllerTest {

   }
   ```
2. Creating a @TestConfiguration class that injects the 'MyValidator' bean as:

   ```
       @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
       @WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
       public class MyControllerTest {
          @TestConfiguration
          static class TestConfig {
             @Bean
             MyValidator getMyValidator(){
                 return new MyValidator();
             }
          }
          // tests
       }
   ```

   More on this can be found here : https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-init-a-bean-for-testing/